# How to find "deploymentTimeStamp" which use when I will execute the command "swanky call" with swanky-cli

Tags: astar

```
% swanky --version
@astar-network/swanky-cli/1.0.0-beta.4 darwin-x64 node-v16.4.0
```

- I used "swanky cli" to deploy the contract to swanky-node.

```
% swanky contract deploy flipper --gas 10000000000 --args false --account alice
✔ Initialising OK
✔ Getting WASM OK
✔ Connecting to node OK
✔ Deploying OK
✔ Writing config OK
Contract deployed!
Contract address: 5EbFSCUyZvigPoYnRbQfqKPCANBEt35HauFD7Q1CLRY7BjK8
```

- I want to call this contract using the "swanky conatract call" command.
- When I call the "swanky contract call" command without the -t option, I get the following error.

```
% swanky contract call --contractName=flipper -m get -g 10000000000     
ERROR: Module error: Contracts: ContractNotFound

No contract was found at the specified address.
    Error: Command failed: cargo contract call --contract 5E5Wf6XHHcqZr3wbeqJsVeh4E3aFYA7rgrJ34Yjyu8EZBTZ7 --message get  
    --suri //Alice --gas 10000000000 --url ws://127.0.0.1:9944
```

- I think I need to use the -t option to specify the contract I just deployed, but I don't know how to specify it.
- Looking at the standard out of swanky node, I can't find anything that looks like a timestamp.
- Can you tell me the correct way to specify this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I found a destination for timestamps on deploy.
- It's "swanky.config.json"!
- Each time I deploy it adds a contract address and a timestamp.

Comment: You're right - there's a field in `swanky.config.json` -> `contracts -> [contract_name] -> deployments[]` that keeps track of where and when you deployed.

Note on the `call` command though - it's only a proxy to `cargo contract call` for now (will be switched to polkadot-api), so you can actually just use that directly if you need more flexibility.